# Stable text feed for vim through vimserver

Tags: c, shell, vim

I am searching for a highly stable way to feed text (output of a program) into vim through vimserver. Assume that I have started a (g)vim session with `gvim --servername vim myfile`. The file `myfile` contains a (unique) line `OUT:` which marks the position where the text should be pasted. I can straight forwardly achieve this from the commandline with `vim --servername vim --remote-send ':%s/OUT:/TEXT\\rOUT:/<Enter>'`. I can repeatedly feed more text using the same command. Inside a C-program I can execute it with `system()`. However `TEXT` which is dynamic and arbitrary (received as a stream in the C-program) needs to be passed on the command line and hence it needs to be escaped. Furthermore using the replacement command `%s` vim will jump to the position where `TEXT` is inserted. I would like to find a way to paste large chunks of arbitrary text seamlessly in vim. An idea is to have vim read from a posix pipe with `:r pipe` and to write the the string from within the C-program to the pipe. Ideally the solution would be such that I can continuously edit the same file manually without noting that output is added at `OUT:` as long as this location is outside the visible area.

The purpose of this text feed is to create a command line based front end for scripting languages. The blocks of input is entered manually by the user in a vim buffer and is being sent to the interpreter through a pipe using vim's `:! [interpreter]` command. The `[interpreter]` can of course write the output to `stdout` (preceded by the original lines of input) in which case the input line is replaced by input and output (to be distinguished using some leading key characters for instance). However commands might take a long time to produce the actual output while the user might want to continue editing the file. Therefore my idea is to have `[interpreter]` return `OUT:` immediately and to append subsequent lines of output in this place as they become available using vimserver. However the output must be inserted in a way which does not disturb or corrupt the edits possibly made by the user at the same time.

**EDIT**

The proposed solutions seem to work.
However there seem to be at least two caveats: * if I send text two or more times this way the `` part of the commands will not take me back to the original cursor position (if I do it just once still the markers are modified which may interrupt the user editing the file manually) * if the user opens a different buffer (e.g. the online help) the commands will fail (or maybe insert the text in the present buffer)

Any ideas?

Comment: RE your edit: Please stop piling more requirements on the question; rather, it would be interesting what's the use case for all this, to avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: See the modification. I think it over complicates the partial problem discussed here. The edit was rather intended to pass information to everybody at the same time (the requirement that the solution does not disturb the workflow of a user editing the file, was part of the original questions and my edit intended to show where the proposed solutions do interrupt it).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After actually trying, this should work for you:

```
vim --servername vim --remote-send \
    ":set cpo+=C<CR>/OUT:<CR>:i<CR>HELLO<CR>WORLD<CR>.<CR>\`\`"
```

As far as I can see, the only caveats would be the period on a single line, which would terminate `:insert` instead of being inserted, and `<..>` sequences that might be interpreted as keypresses. Also, need to replace any newlines in the text with `<CR>`. However, you have no worries about regular expressions getting muddled, the input is not the command line, the amount of escaping necessary is minimal, and the jumping is compensated for with the double backticks.

Check out `:help 'cpoptions'`, `:help :insert`, and `:help ''`.

Comment: It is definitely an improvement. However I think it's still a bit more complicated. I need to meet not only restrictions for vim commands in this case, but also restrictions of the  shell. For instance in your expression I need to escape backslashes in the string to be inserted. Changing it to `vim --servername vim --remote-send ':set cpo+=C<CR>/OUT:<CR>:i<CR>\012<CR>OUT:<CR>.<CR>\`\`'` (with single quotes) I still need to escape at least single quotes. Furthermore the total length of the string will be restricted (otherwise I will get "Argument list too long"). Note also string may be utf8.

Comment: In that case, you could leverage `:.-1r` to read from a tempfile instead of `:i`, and `:call delete(...)` to remove the file, and thus notify that it is done with insertion. I tried doing it with fifos, and while it looks like a good idea, it made my system a bit unstable. Going the file way, no escaping needed at all, also no length or encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Probably I would however read from a pipe and not delete it. This should avoid that the string is physically written to disk each time. But see my edits to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with the escaping, I would rather use lower-level functions. Use `let lnum = search('^OUT:$')` to locate the marker line, and `call setline(lnum, [text, 'OUT:'])` to insert the text and the marker line again.

Comment: Using low-level functions seems to be very plausible to me. What are the requirements for `text` in your `call setline(lnum, [text, 'OUT:'])`? Does it need to be escaped? What would it look like if I would read the text from a file using low-level commands?

Comment: The only thing you cannot directly insert is a newline (`\n`) character (pass additional List elements instead), all other characters are inserted as-is, so no escaping inside Vim; try it!

Comment: I will try, but it seems to me that, as below, I need to escape at least single quotes `'`.

Comment: Yes, to generate a proper literal string, `'` must be doubled to `''`. But that's in your shell script wrapper, not escaping inside Vim.

Comment: Seems to work. However, see my edit to the question.

Comment: You have to handle marks and check for the right buffer (in my solution, `search()` will return `0` in that case) yourself.

Comment: Can I retrieve the result of `search`, i.e. `lnum`, with a `system()` call or similar? In this case the program feeding the text into vim would need to pause. Otherwise content would be lost.